# Wanting to loop through array of IDs to fetch data from API

Tags: javascript, api, loops, vue.js, axios

in this app, I'm fetching the IDs from one API and passing them into a second API and trying to display the property overviewList.overview.lifeTimeData.energy for each ID from the second API, but in this example, all I can do is display the property of the first index. How do I loop through the array of IDs and display the property of each ID? Here's a live working version of what I have so far, the code is under components > HelloWorld.vue. I know I need to loop through the array of IDs, but I don't know how.

https://codesandbox.io/live/68gQlN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not very clear.

But when you do

```
      axios.get(
        this.host +
          this.domain +
          `/site/` + ids[0] + `/overview?` +
          this.apiKey,
        this.config
      )
```

You need to run this query for each id right.
Your methods should look more like this:

```
methods: {
  async getSiteDetails() {
    let ids = [];
    await axios.get(
      this.host +
        this.domain +
          "/sites/list?sortProperty=name&sortOrder=ASC&" +
        this.apiKey,
      this.config
    )
    .then((...responses) => {
      this.siteList = responses[0].data;
      ids = this.siteIdList.concat(responses[0].data.sites.site).map(x => x.id);
    })
    
    ids.forEach(this.getOverviewList);
  },
  async getOverviewList(id) {
    axios.get(
      this.host +
        this.domain +
        `/site/` + id + `/overview?` +
        this.apiKey,
      this.config
    )
    .then(((...responses) => {
        this.overviewList[id] = responses[0].data;
    }))
    .catch(errors => {
      console.log(errors);
    });
  },
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I've been trying for so long to get this to work.